# Finding the area of $GCD$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

> $\DeclareMathOperator{\cm}{cm}$On a plate in the shape of an equilateral triangle $ABC$ with area $16\sqrt{3}\cm^2$, a rod $GD$ of height $8\cm$, is fixed vertically. $G$ is a point on the plate. If the areas of the triangles $AGD$ and $BGD$ are both equal to $4\sqrt{19}\cm^2$, find the area of the triangle $CGD$ (in $\cm^2$).

Comment: Use Pythagoras' to find AG, BG, then use the cosine rule to find angle BAG; then find angle GAC from BAG, and use the cosine rule on GAC to find CG; you can then use this to calculate the area

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw Thanks . But are there any alternate method to this question because it was an aptitude question?

Comment: What sort of alternate method are you hoping for?

Comment: @BenedictRandallShaw So I found an answer on the internet {
1/2*BG*8=4√19 so BG^2=19-16=3 so √3/2*8-√3=3√3 . now area=1/2*3√3*8=12√3} But I am not getting it how BG^2=3?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a sketch of steps you can take to find the answer.  You will need to fill in missing details.

First, note that $AB=BC=CA=8\texttt{ cm}$.  Next, we have $$AG=BG=\sqrt{19}\texttt{ cm}\,.$$  Thus, the triangle $AGB$ is isosceles, and so the line segment $GM$ is perpendicular to $AB$, where $M$ is the midpoint of $AB$.  That is, $$GM^2=BG^2-BM^2=\big(\sqrt{19}\texttt{ cm}\big)^2-\left(\frac{8\texttt{ cm}}{2}\right)^2=\big(\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}\big)^2\,.$$
Consequently, $GM=\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}$.  Finally, note that $CM=4\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}$, whence
$$CG=CM-GM=3\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}$$
and the area of the triangle $CGD$ is
$$\frac{1}{2}\,GC\cdot CG=\frac{1}{2}\,\big(8\texttt{ cm}\big)\,\big(3\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}\big)=12\sqrt{3}\texttt{ cm}^2\,.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Batominovski. Much appreciated.